# ошибка auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

пишу команду auto-py-to-exe. И выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)                                                                                                                             
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code           
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\auto-py-to-exe.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\__main__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import ui
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\ui.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import __version__ as pyinstaller_version_string
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PyInstaller import compat
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 165, in <module>
    is_ms_app_store = is_win and os.path.getsize(python_executable) == 0
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
OSError: [WinError 1920] Доступ к этому файлу из системы отсутствует: 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe'
```

Подскажите что делать?

Comment: Если вы хотите удалить свой вопрос - кнопка удаления прямо под ним.

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка указывает, что у программы нет доступа к файлу python.exe, что, вероятно, является результатом ограничений политики Windows.

Одним из возможных решений является запуск команды с правами администратора.